# "I being" or "me being"?

Tags: pronouns, predicate-nominative

Is "This is me being an idiot" correct?

"This is I being an idiot" sounds weird to me, but what about the subject complement?

Comment: 'It are we', 'It is we' or 'It's us'? The 'copular _be_ must always take the nominative case: when in England, do as the Romans did' rule was fiatted onto English at some point, if memory serves me right. There's been a counter-revolution, and real living people say 'This is me being an idiot'.

Comment: ... 'This is he being an idiot'?

Comment: [Google 5grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+is+me+being+a%2Cthis+is+I+being+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20is%20me%20being%20a%3B%2Cc0) for "this is me being a" and "this is I being a" show a tremendous surge in the use of the former since about 2006. Searching further, I've found only commaed variants to the expected and more usual  'This is me being a woman' etc. // The latter flatlines throughout.

Answer (score 1):

The Chicago Manual says that "strictly speaking" the pronoun should be in the nominative case.

However, as [another reference](https://www.thoughtco.com/subject-complement-grammar-1692001) points out "the objective case (me) is now in general use (It's me)".

Comment: The only thing that can stop this being counted as a duplicate is the fact that the sentence is 'This is I being an idiot' rather than 'This is I'. 'It is I/me' has been covered in great depth, and if CMoS _still_ has ' "strictly speaking" the pronoun should be in the nominative case' (I assume in 'It is I/he.')  (and I don't know what the double inverted commas are intended to signify) it needs revising urgently.